# Dynamic printing with python

Tags: python, dynamic, printing

I kinda need help with specific dynamic printing to text file,

I can perform dynamic printing with 1,2,3,4,5 in terminal but when i try to print to text file, it doesn't work..
Ex:
list = 1,2,3,4,5
print list dynamically

1  //1 is changes to 2 and then to 3 and so on

but when print to file it does this:
1
2
3
4
5

Anyone have got any idea on this? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "dynamic" printing?  A simple program showing the problem and the output you're seeing would be helpful.

Comment: I assume by 'dynamic printing' you mean using '\r' (carriage return) to go back to the beginning of the line in a shell. When you write these 'special characters' to a file, they are simply written there just like any other character. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: hi guys, 
thanks for responding, the code is as follows:

for i in range(1,20):
  stdout.write("/r%d" & i)
  stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(0.5)

normal printing would be 
1
2
3 

this code replaces "1" and "2" takes over and so on, 

I am wondering if its possible to print it to a text file with the exact events

thanks in advance